# How do I read a lambda's inline policy via the aws-cli?

Tags: aws-lambda

When I view the Permissions tab of my Lambda in the AWS web console I see the message:

```
Lambda obtained this information from the following policy statements:
Inline policy my-lambda-policy, statement 4
```

In the Function Policy section it shows:

```
This Lambda function's policy is empty.
```

How can I view the inline policy via the aws-cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a multi-step process.

Get the lambda's role:

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name myfunction --query Configuration.Role --output text

#arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-LambdaRole-77MTY580HEW6
```

List role policies:

```
aws iam list-role-policies --role-name my-LambdaRole-77MTY580HEW6 --query PolicyNames --output text

#my-lambda-policy
```

Get specific policy:

```
aws iam get-role-policy --role-name my-LambdaRole-77MTY580HEW6 --policy-name my-lambda-policy
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function can gain permissions via IAM role or via a resource policy that is explicitly assigned to the function itself. I think what you are talking about is a function policy, thats what you see in the `Permission` tab under the section called "Function Policy".

If you lambda function has a function policy/ resource policy attached, you can use the below command to view it via cli.

```
aws lambda get-policy --function-name testInlinePolicy --profile personal --region ap-southeast-2
```

hope you find this answer useful.

Comment: As mentioned in the question there is no explicitly assigned function policy.

Comment: Just realized that you are the one posted the question. Do you really have a question or you are just recording your findings. Because I am wondering why an answer is posted just one min after the question is posted.

Comment: It is permitted to answer your own question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I know that. I was just surprised to see the answer posted by asker with in a minute I was wondering why would he post a question if he knows the answer already. All good. Apologies for the attention.

Comment: I didn't know the answer when I posted the question, but then I figured it out shortly after.